# Proportion testing in R

Tags: r, proportion

I have a dataframe in R that contains the the total number of girls and boys at a school, along with the total number of girls and boys who did not complete their summer reading list. I would like to do a proportions test to see if the fraction of boys who do not complete their reading is significantly higher than the fraction of girls;

```
head(tmp)

       TOTAL  INCOMPLETE
BOYS   1345     534
GIRLS  798      308
```

Using R, I run the proportion test;

```
prop.test(x=c(534,308),n=c(1345,798),alternative='less',correct=F)

2-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

data:  c(534, 308) out of c(1345, 798)
X-squared = 0.2569, df = 1, p-value = 0.6939
alternative hypothesis: less
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.00000000  0.04690901
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.3970260 0.3859649
```

I am not sure how to interpret the output. Is the fraction of boys that don't read significantly higher than girls?

Comment: Is the issue that you don't know how to interpret the p-value? We have numerous answers on site about doing that. Or is it that you don't know how p-values come into it at all? Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself, and indicate the specific help you need at the point you struck difficulty.

Comment: Also, additionally to what @Glen_b mentioned, by specifying `alternative = 'less'` you're investigating if the first proportion (boys) is statistically significantly less than the second proportion (girls). I don't know if you designed an experiment for that, but it makes more sense to use `alternative = 'greater'`, as the observed proportion for the boys is larger than the girls.

Comment: @AntoniosK the alternative should not be chosen by examining the data but by prior considerations relevant to the question of interest and subject-area knowledge. If it is chosen with reference to the data, p-values no longer mean what they should (typically, p-values are artificially small).

Comment: Totally agree @Glen_b. That's why I mentioned the experiment design, but maybe I wasn't clear. No one should chose the test (especially one-tailed) after observing the results. What I meant was that if his experiment design focused on spotting whether the boys % is stat sign less than girls %, then by just observing the data (39.7% > 38.6%) he didn't have to bother running the prop test.

Comment: @AntoniosK That makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. so @AntoniosK, how to i prove the difference didn't actually occur by chance? I thought that is was the prop test was telling me?

Comment: It does @mudsmith, but within the prop test there are 3 variations: 2-tailed test, 1-tailed test (in favour of the boys, or in favour of the girls). Which one to chose is mostly based on your experiment design and your objective. The test you perform here means that you have a prior knowledge (or intuition) that the boys will perform worse than the girls.

Comment: Also, don't forget that any difference (even very small ones) will be found statistically significant if they still exist after collecting many many observations. So, the (real) question is "do I have enough observation to conclude that the test is powerful enough for my purposes?". The proper way to find that out is to (a) specify your objective in advace, (b) obtain the efficient sample size based on some statistical formulas. Try to look those up and everything will get much clearer.

Comment: Great advice @AntoniosK. Last question, is there any practical interpretation of the confidence intervals for a 2 sample proportion test. Obviously I see here that the interval contains zero, which supports our hypothesis conclusion. But if it did not contain zero (p-value is < .05), how would I interpret the CI in that case?

Comment: Of course there is. In any case, no matter what the p value is, CI show you where you expect the difference between the two proportions to be. When you spot a stat sign difference (p < .05) then you expect zero not to be included in that range. In other words, one of the proportions is "always" (95% condifence) bigger than the other. If p > .05 then zero will be included, which means that there is likelihood that the difference between the proportions is actually zero.

Comment: So, in your specific case (output you provided) the interpretation of the CIs is a bit tricky because you specified alternative='less' and you "forced" the test to believe that the % of girls is bigger than the boys and the CIs tell you that in fact the % of boys can be up to 0.04699 bigger than the % of the girls. -1 on the left side is created because of your specification. If you perform a 2-tailed test you'll see how the CIs change, as they are not "forced" to believe that one % is bigger than the other in general.

Comment: @Glen_b The sentence ' p-values no longer mean what they should (typically, p-values are artificially small)' is intriguing to me, and I wonder if you have any code or reference where I can prove this statement to myself with a computer simulation.

Comment: It's simple enough that you can do it even without simulation. Assume H0 is true and I have two exactly identical populations (or equivalently my samples from the same population). If I choose to do some 1-tailed test by looking to see which direction to test for by observing the sample, I will generally\* be twice as likely to get into some rejection region as I should be - my p-values will be half what they should. \*(There are some exceptions, such as a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, where it's not exactly twice.)

Comment: @Glen_b It makes a lot of sense, although I guess that if you set the threshold high by always choosing a double-tailed test, you can "justify the fairness" of running proportion testing even when you come into data already collected... Or not... so tricky...

Answer (score 2):

Statistical tests and their interpretation makes sense only when you have previously defined your objective and designed your experiment in order to capture statistically significant differences based on your objective (see my comments above for the reason behind it).

In many cases, however, someone was given a dataset and needs to compare percentages. In that case you interpret the p-value as a metric which classifies your difference as significant or not. You don't know how confident you are about that classification (this is what the statistical power of test exists for).

In your case `prop.test(x=c(534,308),n=c(1345,798),alternative='less',correct=F)` is not useful as the % of boys is observed to be higher than the girls. So, there's no point in investigating if it is smaller.

You can either:

a) Use `prop.test(x=c(534,308),n=c(1345,798),alternative='greater',correct=F)` if you have strong evidence that the boys % is generally expected to be larger than the girls, or

b)Use `prop.test(x=c(534,308),n=c(1345,798),correct=F)` if you don't have any idea which proportion is expected to be higher generally. This is the most common way to investigate differences in %.

All 3 tests will tell you that there's no statistically significant difference, based on what you observed on this dataset.

It will be useful to search about : p value interpretation, statistical power, efficient sample size, designing experiments, designing AB tests.